# how to create model, controller and view files in Croogo cms?

Tags: croogo

I am trying to create a contact form with validation in Croogo, I don't know where to create the ctp files and the controller for it. I did this in cakephp but I could not do the same in Croogo. Help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created it in the nodes folder. As this is the first time I am using this I struggled with it. I have created the view files and the controller files in the respective view and controller folder in the nodes folder.